# Need help in forming Regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text block with one or more functions in the following form

```
$fn{{#split(${{node::1234}},${{node::1345}},',')}}
```

I need a regex to collect the functions from the text using a regex. 
I was trying to use the following one:

```
/\$(fn|)\{{2}(((?!\}\}).)+)\}{2}/g
```

But it is capturing only `$fn{{#split(${{node::1234}}` - instead of capturing the whole function.

```js
const input = "$fn{{#split(${{node::1234}},${{node::1345}},',')}}";
const rx = /\$(fn|)\{{2}(((?!\}\}).)+)\}{2}/g
const matches = input.match(rx);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: What is the expected result in this case? Do you need the whole function as match? Or parts of it?

Comment: Usually in situations like these you need a parser, rather than regex. I'd suggest you consider it. Regex is bad tool as you have to explicitly allow all combinations of valid syntax. It's very easy to either make it not exhaustive enough or too permissive or *both* and thus fail to match correctly.

Comment: @VLAZ - Thanks for your suggestion. Can you let me know how can I write one parser for this?

Answer (score 1):

This works at least with given example `/\$((fn|)\{{2}(.*\}{2})*)/g` .

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. But if there are other texts between two such expressions it is capturing the whole together. Like this - 
`$fn{{#split(${{node::1234}},${{node::1345}},',')}} Some Other texts $fn{{#split(${{node::1234}},${{node::1345}},',')}}`

Comment: For even more complex strings, probably become true that you require to write a parser... `recursive descent parser` is quite easy to implement and seems to fit your requirements

Comment: I think this should work - `/\$((fn|)\{{2}([^\s\\]*\}{2})*)/g`